# Knockout js "IF" binding to a function receiving parameters and returning boolean

Tags: knockout.js

I want to be able to show or hide certain DOM elements based on a array of say role names. The thing is that I want to check the role or roles in html.

Something like:

```
<div data-bind="if: isInRole('Admin', 'Editor')">
```

or

```
<div data-bind="if: isInRole(['Admin', 'Editor'])">
```

The above solution doesn't seem to work for me. Any suggestions/alternatives?

Comment: How is `inInRole` defined, what does it return? What do you mean on "doesn't seem to work for me"? Are there any errors in your browser JS console?

Comment: Console says 'unable to parse binding' and I think maybe the binding syntax is wrong. I don't know if u can have funcs with params in binding. The `isInRole` has such an structure: `function (param) { return true; }`

Comment: Please post the complete error message! Also your view model code would be helpfull... because your code should work: http://jsfiddle.net/kuY5E/1/

Answer (score 5):

Comments by @nemesv are spot on: you probably have an error or problem in code you're not showing in your question. Nonetheless, here's a setup that may help you find and fix that error you're experiencing.

Your method signature `IsInRole` isn't congruent with the input parameter, which is an array of roles. If you change that to `IsInAnyRole` things may become clearer, something like this should work just fine:

```html
<div data-bind="if: isInAnyRole(['admin', 'editor'])">Protected div!</div>
```

With the following view model:

```
var vm = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.roles = ko.observableArray(["editor", "user"]);

    self.isInAnyRole = function(targetRoles) {
        return targetRoles.some(function(el) { return self.roles().indexOf(el) !== -1; });
    }
};
```

You can check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2WhZF/) for a demo of the above. If you change the roles of the view model to something other than "editor" or "admin" the message will disappear.